# Re-display invalid data entry when expecting a number upon validation error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Let us say that the user submits a form.  One of the fields was invalid, so the form gets re-rendered.  When in the process of re-rendering the form: I check to see if the submitted value for that attribute was invalid.  If so: then show that invalid data entry with some additional text.

Here is what I have so far.  It is close but isn't working completely:

```
<%= form_for(blog) do |f| %>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :age %>

    <% if f.object.age %>
      <% if f.object.errors.include?(:age) %>
        <%= f.text_field :age, value: "Submitted: #{f.object.age} was bad" %>
      <% else %>
        <%= f.text_field :age %>
      <% end %>
    <% else %>
      <%= f.text_field :age %>
    <% end %>

  </div>

  <div class="actions">
    <%= f.submit %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

So I am saying: "Hey Rails: if the user has already submitted this form, *and* the value the user submitted for this attribute of `age` was invalid, then re-render the submitted value within the input, along with some additional text."

The issue I am having is that it will not show the error input correctly.  For example: if the user inputs "abcd" into the input field, then when the form re-renders upon failing validations, the input field *should* say: "Submitted: abcd was bad".  Instead it says "Submitted: 0 was bad".

I am close.  The ultimate question is: Why is it displaying `0`?  Why isn't it displaying `"abcd"`? The next question is: "How can I make it display `"abcd"`?

Is this behavior because I have the following validation? :

```
    validates :age, numericality: true
```

If so: how can I have the validation to ensure it is a number, but also re-display the value the user entered?

Comment: Have you considered using [simple_form](https://github.com/plataformatec/simple_form)? It handles all of this for you out-of-the-box; placing error messages below the relevant input fields.

Comment: @TomLord I am more just trying to figure out this odd behavior and making it work as expected.  I agree the implementation above could be better, but  I just want to be able to display the submitted value, as opposed to displaying `0` for whatever reason it is doing that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works.  Just grab the submitted value from the `params` hash:

```
<div class="field">
  <%= f.label :age %>

  <% if f.object.age %>
    <% if f.object.errors.include?(:age) %>
      <%= f.text_field :age, value: "Submitted #{params[:blog][:age]} is bad" %>
     <% else %>
      <%= f.text_field :age %>
    <% end %>
  <% else %>
    <%= f.text_field :age %>
  <% end %>
</div>
```

It appears that `f.object.age` does not work because the `age` attribute is of type `integer`.  because of this: within the writer method for the `age` attribute:

```
def age=(value)
  ...
end
```

Somewhere within that setter what probably happens is that rails attempts to convert the submitted value with: `to_i`.  When you do `to_i` on a string it returns `0`, so when you attempt `f.object.age` it will return `0` because the writer attempted to convert the string.

The other tricky thing is the `text_field` method.  Rails has some magic going on in there.  For example: if there was nothing special going on: the following *would* successfully display the submitted value as opposed to `0`:

```
<%= f.text_field :age %>
```

So somewhere within the `text_field` method, rails looks to see if that attribute of `age` was invalid, and if it was, then it specifies as the `value` the *submitted* value.

Without digging into the rails source code, it is tough to say how `text_field` figures out if the attribute was previously submitted, AND if the submitted value was invalid.  Thus: if one dug within the rails source code I am sure you could clean up the conditionals up above once you figure out how `text_field` displays the submitted value (ex: `'abcd'` as opposed to the converted value from the setter (ex: `'0'`).

Nonetheless: the above code works and does what is desired.

Answer (score 0):

This is failing because you're calling `f.object.age` in an interpolated string, not the value submitted.

Since you're validating the numericality on age, your `'abcd'` input will never pass validation and therefore would never saved.

So when you're  calling `.age` on that object, you're only getting the default value, or the last value that passed validation and was saved. Your `'abcd'` string would never have been saved.

An easier way to show the error would be to do:

`f.object.errors.full_messages_for(:age)`

You could also try adding a custom error message:

`validates_numericality_of :age, message: '%{value} is not a valid age'`

Comment: so how do I display the value submitted? Ex: input of `'abcd'`?

Comment: You would have to figure out a way to pass the bad string to your view. It would be much easier to just display the default error message and omit the invalid user input.

Comment: It is odd to me that this is so difficult.  If I did not have any of that additional input text and just left it like this: `<%= f.text_field :age %>` then when it fails validations it properly re-displays whatever value  was submitted.  How is that able to grab the submitted entry upon failed validation?  Maybe if I figured that out then I could apply it to this situation.  Seems like Rails is doing some magic...

Comment: See the edit about adding a custom error message. That should do the trick.

Comment: That does not give me the ability to redisplay the users submitted value within the form input.  I want to know how I can grab the users submitted value and redisplay it within the input.